# Rails order by two different associations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

How can I sort from two different columns?

```
def order_by_percentage
  joins(:school_annual_data).order('school_annual_data.survey3_low_percent DESC')
  joins(:school_eligibility_data).order('school_eligibility_data.low_income_percent DESC')   
end
```

if `joins(:school_eligibility_data).order('school_eligibility_data.low_income_percent DESC')` is nil, I want to sort by `joins(:school_eligibility_data).order('school_eligibility_data.low_income_percent DESC')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class YourModel
    scope :survey3, -> { where(survey3_low_percent: nil).reorder(low_income_percent: :desc) }
    scope :low, -> { where(low_income_percent: nil).reorder(survey3_low_percent: :desc) }

    def self.new_order
        survey3.to_a + low.to_a
    end
end
```

or

```
joins(:school_annual_data).order("COALESCE(school_annual_data.survey3_low_perce‌​nt, school_eligibility_data.low_income_percent)")
```

this will be like `survey3_low_perce‌​nt || low_income_percent`

Comment: How can I order by which percent is higher from the two columns?